# How to use routerLink in submit button

Tags: angular

I want to use routerLink in my Form submit button.

when I use routerLink then my form not got submit.
It shows "your form is not connected".

This my HTML code-

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="planForm"(ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"class="form-group">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-1" routerLink="/plan-list">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I got this **error** :

> "Form submission canceled because the form is not connected"

Answer (score 2):

in `HTML` file

```
<form [formGroup]="planForm">
 <button (click)="submit()"></button>
</form>
```

in `ts` file you can write your `router` in a better way by [**router**](https://angular.io/api/router/Router)

```
 constructor(
  private router:Router //instanciate a router
)
```

your submit method like below

```
submit(){
    this.router.navigate(['/plan-list']) //your router URL need to pass it here
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When your button is submit type then you should use onSubmit() function like this for navigating when click event handled

```
onSubmit() {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/plan-list');
}
```